# tidyverse spread function error

Tags: r, tidyverse, spread

I've used the `spread` function in tidyverse before, and it worked fine. Now, however, it raises this error message for all uses of the spread function:

```
df <- data_frame(x = c('a', 'b'), y = 1:2)
df %>% spread(x, y)
```

> Error in synthetic.instrument(primary_id = primary_id, currency = currency,  : 
>     object 'y' not found
>
> Error in synthetic.instrument(primary_id = primary_id, currency = currency,  : 
>     argument "memberratio" is missing, with no default

What is causing the error?

Comment: maybe a library conflict, try `df %>% tidyr::spread(x, y)`

Comment: Run `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` and look for `"spread"` in the result.  Or be cool and do `any(conflicts() == "spread")`

Comment: searching the error messages suggests the `FinancialInstruments` package is throwing the error

Comment: thank you SymbolixAU and Rich Scriven. it is library conflict, especially  FinancialInstruments  package.